# YouTube API is adding 101 uses for each request instead of one

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API to search for information about videos and to search for videos. However, whenever I make a request, it charges **101** uses instead of 1, and I am reaching the daily quota quickly. I have only made about 27 requests, but as you can see

[image: in this picture],

I have already used 2,727 requests out of my daily 10,000 limit. I've tried to figure out why this is happening, but I haven't found anything. Why is this happening? Any help is greatly appreciated. Please help, as this is negatively affecting this program. Thanks!

I am using Unirest to get the data, and this is what the code is:

```
var req = unirest("GET", `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=${query}&part=snippet&maxResults=1&key=${API_KEY}&type=video`)
```

Comment: Troubleshooting this issue is very hard, if not impossible at all, without having any information about the client that's making the API request, or seeing the client code.

Comment: @Sam Sorry. I am using Unirest to get the data, with this code: ```var req = unirest("GET", `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=${query}&part=snippet&maxResults=1&key=${API_KEY}&type=video`)```.

Comment: Have you checked the [quota  calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)  Quota isnt just one request to one quota used with the YouTube api its based upon data requested and returned.